# What does it mean if algebra $A$ is free in the variety $V(A)$

Tags: universal-algebra, congruence-relations

I am studying chapter 14 of Burris and Sankappanavar on fully invariant congruences. In Lemma 14.7 is proved that if $\theta$ is a fully invariant congrence on $T(X)$, then for $p = q \in Id(X)$ we have:
$$
T(X)/\theta \vDash p=q \Leftrightarrow \langle p,q \rangle \in \theta
$$
The proof ends by the following remark: 
$$
T(X)/\theta \vDash p=q \Leftrightarrow V(T(X)/\theta) \vDash p=q
$$
because the same identities are satisfied by a class of algebra's and the variety generated by this class. Upon this notion is concluded that $T(X)/\theta$ is free in $V(T(X)/\theta)$.

But I don't know how to support this claim, maybe because I lack intuition on `being a free algebra'.

http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/ualg.html

Comment: Intuitively you can think of a free algebra $\mathbf F$ in a variety $\mathcal  V$ has being an algebra which satisfies all the equations satisfied by the variety (thus $\mathbf F \in \mathcal V$) and no other identity (thus $\mathbf F$ is free).

Comment: @amrsa You also need to take into account the generating set $X$. The cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}$ is free in the variety of all groups, but it satisfies an identity not satisfied by all groups.

Comment: @Eran Indeed! I was very imprecise. As you claim $\mathbb Z$ is free in over the variety of all groups over, for example, $\{1\}$.